# Chromium stays in backgound

Tags: chromium

I'm running Thunderbird 31.0, FireFox 13.0 and Chromium 36.0.1985.143 on Ubuntu 14.04. Both Thunderbird and Chromium are open and running.

When I click on a link in an email in Thunderbird I expected to switch from Thunderbird to Chromium to the foreground to display the website associated with the link. What happens instead is that Chromium wiggles in the Launcher and Thunderbird is still displayed. I have to click on Chromium to see the website. I don't have this problem with FireFox 13.0.

Is this normal behaviour with Chromium on Ubuntu or can you change this so that you switch from Thunderbird to Chromium automatically?

Comment: Try middle clicking on links to open them.

Comment: Thunderbird 31.7, Chrome 43.0.2357.81, with same behaviour. The Focus Prevention Level setting (from the @Raeff Refai's answer took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my recollection, if the browser window is open, be it Chromium or Firefox, it will only shake the icon and not bring the window to the front. I do not believe there is a way to bring the browser window to the front in this situation without getting deeper than a toggle switch in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager
2. Go to: General Options → Focus & Raise Behaviour tab
3. Then change *Focus Prevention Level* to *Off*